# Paging predicate in hazelcast

Tags: java, paging, hazelcast

There is a problem with the pagination predicate in the version Hazelcast 3.3.2, 
The Hazelcast map contains 20 data, 
When we try to get the limited data using pagingpredicate (Ex : 10), It is not returning the first 10 data, If I give pagingpredicate.nextPage(), Am getting 10 data where few data are already given in first ten data.
I mean to say If I hit pagingpredicate (Ex: 10), It is not properly returning the first 10 data, It is mixing with the remaing data in the map, It happens even for pagingPredicate.nextPage() too...

Thanks and Regards,
Hari Prasanth.L

Answer (score 0):

When I tried `PagingPredicate` in Hazelcast 3.4.1, I faced the same problem whereby my Map value object didn't implement the `Comparable` interface.

The problem was solved when I added `Comparator<Map.Entry>` into `PagingPredicate` constructor (which fixed the order.)